# Implementation of seekbar start code function write in stop fuction in media player

Tags: android, android-support-library

i want to convert write onprogress function into stop. means when is release seekbar then volume is up and down.

```
 sB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i/*progress*/, boolean b) {
           aM.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,i,0);
           // Log.i("Progress","Called"+i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.i("Start","Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                            Log.i("Stop","Called");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this::

```
private int volumLevel = 0;

sB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i/*progress*/, boolean b) {
       if(b){
       volumLevel = i;
       }
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        Log.i("Start","Called");
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

         aM.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,volumnLevel,0);
         Log.i("Stop","Called");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

asper our knowledge `onStopTrackingTouch` event is called after releasing seekbar, so you can update your volume when called.

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
      //update your volume using 
     seekBar.getProgress();
}
```